# Why does xcode allow me to use bool variables when using C language

Tags: c, boolean

I am working on a C project and since I have a mac, I am doing it in Xcode. I am using ANSI-C. Everything is working good so far, but I noticed Xcode allows me to compile and run when I do something like the following:

```
bool values[8] = { false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false };
```

As far as I know, there are no built-in boolean types in C, so I suspect Xcode is assuming I am writing C++. How can I disable this? I would like it to strictly allow only pure ANSI-C. Syntax highlighting is set to C, my file is called main.c I don't know what else can I do to disallow this?

Thanks.

Comment: i think i should help H2CO3 in his struggle against Xcode tag. this question has nothing to do with Xcode

Comment: Actually, the Xcode tag might be appropriate here.  This question isn't strictly about C.  It's about something normally not allowed in C that Xcode allows.

Comment: Alex, what include statements do you have?

Comment: Hi, I just have these two:

#include <stdio.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro.h>

Comment: I removed the allegro include and now the booleans are not allowed. So yeah, that was it. Thanks, if you want, post it as an answer and I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: @nhgrif Xcode isn't a compiler, so is irrelevant here, and that's the point. Of course, most newbies don't get that distinction, so it's kind of understandable that so many people are confused on that point.

Comment: For this to be valid, it's enough to have something like `typedef enum { false, true } bool;` in any header.

Answer (score 1):

Though your problem appears resolved by excluding allegro, I hope this is at least somewhat helpful regardless. For establishing specific C-dialect settings, do the following:

1. Select your project in the solution explorer (the one with the blue Xcode app icon). The project -settings editor will open on the right.
2. In the project-settings editor across the top is a series of clickable labels, including Basic All | Combined Levels. Select **All** and **Combined**.
3. Roll down the settings configuration page until approximately 60% and you'll find a section called **Apple LLVM 5.0 Language**. Locate the setting:  **C Language Dialect**.
4. Choose your poison. For ANSI-only compliant C, choose **ANSI C [-ansi]**

Thats it.